# How to recognize a string escaping?

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I have this kind of string :

```
I\x26#39;m happy
```

I was expecting (Obviously, I guess! :) ):

```
I'm happy
```

How can I know what the `\x26#39;` is, and how can I decode it?

Comment: The string was incorrectly encoded twice before being stuck in the HTML or XML. This happens a lot when someone uses code to "reuse" someone else's content and doesn't decode it first. It gets encoded twice which is confusing. I've seen cases when I received RSS that had been encoded three and four times and I had to loop over the text doing decodes until it stopped changing due to decoding. It's an ugly solution but worked.

Comment: @theTinMan I understand your feeling. It should be a mess when strings with different-times encoding are interpolated in one string.

Comment: It was, and blew my mind the first time I ran into it. It was a case where someone encoded an entire HTML document multiple times. I ranted for about an hour then wrote code to fix it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
require "cgi"

CGI.unescapeHTML("\x26#39;")
# => "'"

CGI.unescapeHTML("I\x26#39;m happy")
# => "I'm happy"
```

Comment: Adding to your answer, `\x26`(hex code) represents a `&` and `&#39;` (numerical code) the `'`